# Why is Firebase onChildAdded not being called?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to get all firebase nodes under the "clothing" reference in my firebase database. To do this I attach a `ChildEventListener` to the reference and in the `onChildAdded` callback I add the `Clothing` object to a list of clothing objects, assuming the `onChildAdded` callback is called the number of times there are nodes under the "clothing" reference.

```
mClothingRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                               .getReference()
                               .child("clothing");
final List<Clothing> clothingItems = new ArrayList<>();

mClothingRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot snapshot, String s) {
        Clothing clothing = snapshot.getValue(Clothing.class);
        clothingItems.add(clothing);
        Log.d(TAG, "onChildAdded called");      
    }
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.e(TAG, databaseError.getMessage() + " " + 
        databaseError.getCode() + " " + databaseError.getDetails()  + " " + databaseError.toString());
        mEventBus.post(new ListClothingFailEvent());
    }
    ...
}
```

Here is the database structure:

```
-->root
---->clothing
------>clothing_id
-------->title
-------->category
-------->img_download_url
------>clothing_id_1
-------->title
-------->...
```

I need to get all nodes under the clothing node.

My database security rules are currently:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth == null",
    ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}
```

When the method containing this code is called, the `onChildAdded` callback is not, instead the `onCancelled` callback is with a permission denied database error. Why is this the case?

Comment: When I add a break point on that line it is ignored since that line is never called. The reference url for the clothing node according to the debugger is: https://good-deal-9a0b2.firebaseio.com/clothing which seems right

Comment: @TomFinet Can you share your complete activity code ?

Comment: This code is not in the activity, but it is called from the activity using the `mCatalogRepository.loadClothing()`. I'll add it to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display that data, please use the following code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference clothingRef = rootRef.child("clothing");
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        List<Clothing> clothingItems = new ArrayList<>();
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            Clothing clothing = snapshot.getValue(Clothing.class);
            clothingItems.add(clothing);
        }
        Log.d("TAG", clothingItems);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
clothingRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

Comment: Remember to declare and use the `ArrayList` inside `onDataChange()` method otherwise it will be `null`.

Comment: The problem seems to be that I get a database error permission denied with both my method and your method @Alex Mamo

Comment: Have you changed the permissions for testing purposes to `true` in your Firebase console?

Comment: Now I have and it works. However I now have another problem. In my question I define the `clothingItems` to be final so it cannot be altered. However, I need to add each the clothing items for every time the `onChildAdded` callback is called. How do I get around this?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever there is a change add/delete/modify in any node we should use onChildChanged callback method instead of added. In this method we get the instance of DataSnapshot which is having the new required data.